# How to make drools query "siblings"

Tags: java, drools

I have Java class with this fields:

```
 Public class Parent {
    @Position(0)
    private String parent;
    @Position(1)
    private String child;
 }
```

Then, here are some objects in format:

```
kSession.insert(new Parent("adam", "peter"));
kSession.insert(new Parent("adam", "john"));
```

How to make query "siblings" in drools, in format siblings(String x, String y) and printout like "peter, john"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted that for every parent (name), *query* the siblings having that parent in the working memory, you could achieve that with:

```
query siblings
    accumulate(
        Parent( $p : parent ); $parents: collectSet($p)
    )
    $pName: String() from $parents
    accumulate(
        Parent( parent == $pName, $c: child ); $siblings: collectSet($c)
    )
end
```

the snippet:

```java
session.insert(new Parent("adam", "peter"));
session.insert(new Parent("adam", "john"));

QueryResults qr = session.getQueryResults("siblings");

for (QueryResultsRow queryResultsRow : qr) {
    System.out.println(queryResultsRow.get("$siblings"));
}
```

would print out:

```
[peter, john]
```

It would add additional sysout lines for other parents (not demonstrated here).

Demonstrated with: https://github.com/tarilabs/demo20230401-so75906526/blob/3f9b08c9cc781a37376c1164d65f5144185cd9ed/src/test/java/org/drools/demo/RuleTest.java#L43-L46

Comment: Thanks for answer! How to make this with recursive query? For example, I have query isParent(String x, String y) and output is: adam, peter. Now, how to make siblings(String x, String y) with previous query and this and get "peter, john" output?

Comment: sounds like a very different question, further, is not clear what's the intent of the parameters `x, y` in both queries, further, is not clear how the output of `isParent(x, y)` should be a list when by the name of the query maybe you meant a boolean?